# Jquery Ajax called 'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following javascript:

```
$('#edit_category').on('click','#btn_save_category_name',function(){
    currently_edit.text($('#txt_edit_category').val());

    edit_category_name(currently_edit,current_category_id);
    $('#edit_category').modal('hide')
})

function edit_category_name(name, id){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Category/edit_team_category',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            request: 'ajax',
            name: name,
            id: id
        },
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
}
```

Now when i attempt this i get the following error: `called 'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement.`

But if i comment the function line out aka : `edit_category_name(currently_edit,current_category_id);`

everything works fine.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

**Update my full script**

```
var mode = 'team';
var currently_edit = '';
var current_team_id = 0;
var current_category_id = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //Main click function for Team (selection of team)
    $('#team_wrapper').on('click', '.panel-heading', function () {
        if(mode === 'team'){
            current_team_id = $(this).siblings('small').text()
            title = $(this).find('.text-white').text();
            var i = 100;
            $('#span_search').hide();
            $('#btn_new_team').fadeOut();
            $('.col-lg-3').each(function(){
                $('.alt').toggle('slow');
                $(this).fadeOut(300,function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            });
            $('#team_title').text('Select Category');
            $('#btn_new_category').delay(500).fadeIn();
            $('#selected_team_name').text(title);
            $('#selected').delay(695).fadeIn();
            $('#span_search').delay(500).fadeIn();
            $('#back').delay(500).fadeIn();
            generate_categories();

            mode = 'category';
        }else{
            $(this).next('div').find('a')[0].click();
        }
    })

    $('#team_wrapper').on('click', '.btn_administrate', function(){
        current_team_id = $(this).next('.team_id').text();
        load_team_members(current_team_id);
    });


    //Modal category:

    //create
    $('#btn_create_category').click(function(){
        add_category($('#txt_create_category').val());
        $('#group-form').modal('hide');
        $('#txt_create_category').val('');
    })

    // edit
    $('#team_wrapper').on('click','.team_category_edit',function(){
        current_category_id= $(this).next('input').val()
        edit_mode('txt_edit_category',$(this).closest("div").prev().find("h3"));
    })

    $('#edit_category').on('click','#btn_save_category_name',function(){
        currently_edit.text($('#txt_edit_category').val());

        edit_category_name(currently_edit,current_category_id);
        $('#edit_category').modal('hide')
    })

});


function edit_category_name(name, id){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Category/edit_team_category',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            request: 'ajax',
            name: name,
            id: id
        },
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
```

in this example:

```
    var current_team_id = 1;
var current_category_id = 2;
```

Comment: I'd like to help, but your code snippet looks incomplete. Where do the `currently_edit` and `current_category_id` variables come from? Based on how you're using them it looks like they are jQuery objects, but you're including it in your `data` key to `$.ajax()` as if it were a string?

Comment: I don't see anything in here that would result in a call to a "click" function.

Comment: The two current_category_id and currently_edit is two "global" variables i can add all my code but its quite a large script

Comment: You're passing `currently_edit` to the `name` argument of `edit_category_name`, and then it uses that as the `name:` parameter in the AJAX call. But `currently_edit` is a jQuery object, not the name of anything.

Comment: @zacharytamas added my javascript

Comment: could you Provide `current_category_id` value please ?

Comment: `currently_edit.text(...)` makes no sense. `currently_edit` is an empty character string, not a jQuery object. And you never reassign it.

Comment: It should be  `var currently_edit = {};` `currently_edit.text = $('#txt_edit_category').val()`

Comment: @Barmar true but this isnt what is causing the problem

Comment: If your page is not throwing an error on the currently_edit.text(...) then this must be a jQuery object set somewhere else in your code, otherwise this would in fact throw an error.  Given this is a jQuery object you can't just pass it into the ajax call directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the value of currently_edit?  I am assuming this is a jQuery object not a text value.  Try the following instead.

```
edit_category_name(currently_edit.text(),current_category_id);
```

**Update**

As Barmar mentioned, currently_edit.text(...) is invalid based on what you have shared.  perhaps what you meant to do was:

```
currently_edit = $('#txt_edit_category').val();
```

Comment: @Micheal i have added some of my script (the relevant one

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line `currently_edit.text($('#txt_edit_category').val());`

with this : `currently_edit = $('#txt_edit_category').val();`